# Laravel 5.5 autocomplete method returns a 500 error in one place not another

Tags: jquery-ui, laravel-5, autocomplete, http-status-code-500

I have a simple form to get an autocomplete of an author's name from a table of several thousand.

In my simple form I have:

```
<form>
     <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="authors">authors: </label>
        <input id="authors" value="">
     </div>
</form>
```

The javascript is:

```
<script>
 $(function()
  {
  $( "#authors" ).autocomplete({
  source: "autocompleteAuthors",
  minLength: 3,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

I have a route pointing to a controller:

```
  Route::get('autocompleteAuthors','AutoCompleteController@authors')->name('autocompleteAuthors');
```

and a function in the controller:

```
public function authors()
  {
    $term = Input::get('term');
    $results = array();

    $queries = DB::table('author')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
        ->take(5)->get();

    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = [ 'id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->name];
    }
  return Response::json($results);
  }
```

This works fine.

In a form to edit a quote (part of the edit could be the author) I have the following:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
     <label for="author" style="width:10%">author:</label>
     <input id="author" name="author" value="{{ $author[0]->name }}" style="width:50%">
</div>
```

and the javascript is:

```
  <script>
   $(function()
   {
    $( "#author" ).autocomplete({
    source: "autocompleteAuthors",
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
   }
 });
});
</script>
```

So they are both sending "term" to the same route yet in the second case I get a 500 error.

Can't see any reason for this!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it out. If you set the value in

```html
<input id="author" name="author" value="{{ $author[0]->name }}" style="width:50%">
```

everything fails.

The answer is very simple: set it after the ui is called.

So my form includes:

```html
<div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="author" style="width:10%">author:</label>
       <input id="author" name="author" style="width:50%">
</div>
```

and I invoke the ui with

```js
$(function() {
 $( "#author" ).autocomplete({
  source: "{{ route('autocompleteAuthors') }}",
  minLength: 3,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#q').val('ui.item.value');
  }
 });
});
```

and then I add the initial value:

```js
$( "#author" ).val("{{ $author[0]['name'] }}");
```